# How do I remove commas between a string of characters?

Tags: database, search

How do I remove commas between a string of characters? In all posts. Search and Replace?

I have something like this:
 `xfields` column
...`||ilo_ocen|870,664||kraj|`...

I want to remove commas between "`||ilo_ocen|`" and "`||kraj|`" in all posts.

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we *replace* it with something else. As you said that you want to "remove" comma, you'd replace it with an empty string.

This is Oracle database example (as you didn't state which database you actually use); I believe other databases have a similar function. Sample data in lines #1 - 4; query you might need begins at line #6.

```
SQL> with test (xfields) as
  2    -- sample data
  3    (select '||ilo_ocen|870,664||kraj|'  from dual union all
  4     select 'Little,foot has a big nose' from dual)
  5  -- REPLACE!
  6  select replace(xfields, ',', '') result
  7  from test;

RESULT
--------------------------
||ilo_ocen|870664||kraj|
Littlefoot has a big nose

SQL>
```